# If A has an eigenvector, a, and A = C+D then a is an eigenvector of C and D

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following true?

If  **A** has an eigenvector $\vec{a}$ and if **A** = **C**+**D** then $\vec{a}$ is an eigenvector of **C** and **D**. Furthermore if **A**$\vec{a}$ = $\lambda$$\vec{a}$ and **C**$\vec{a}$ = $\gamma$$\vec{a}$ and **D**$\vec{a}$ = $\beta$$\vec{a}$, then $\lambda$=$\gamma$+$\beta$.

Comment: Have you tried a few examples?  (The first part is not true.)

Comment: False!  See if you can find a counterexample.

Comment: does it change if  D is C transpose

Comment: Of course this couldn't be true.  If you're only given $A$, you can let $C$ be *anything you want it to be*!  Then just fix $D=A-C$.

Comment: In the problem I'm doing C and D are given but I just wanted to ask the question in a general fashion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true...
Let $A,C,D$: $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear operators defined by 
$A(x,y)=(x,y)$ ,
$C(x,y)=(x,0)$ and
$D(x,y)=(0,y)$.. 
So $A=C+D$...
Then $(1,1)$ is an eigen vector of $A$ but $(1,1)$ is neither an eigen vector of $C$ nor an eigen vector of $D$

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackexchange. You are encouraged to learn math typesetting. You can do this by reading about LaTeX online or MathJax tutorials here on the site.